# Why does this MySQL Update query not work?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code for updating the date field for all records that have the field WorkoutID = $currentWorkoutID. When I run the query the dates change to 0000-00-00 and not to the current date. How can I fix this? Btw DB::getInstance() executes the query. I think something is wrong with the actual query?

```
$currentWorkoutID = $_SESSION['GlobalWorkoutID'];
echo $currentWorkoutID;

$date = date("y/m/d");
echo $date;

$sql = "UPDATE workout SET Date = ".$date." WHERE WorkoutID = ".$currentWorkoutID."";
DB::getInstance()->query($sql);
```

Comment: because you have not escaped the variables. Why don't you use prepared statements instead

Comment: My teacher taught me like this

Comment: Try this "UPDATE workout SET Date = ".$date." WHERE WorkoutID = '".$currentWorkoutID.'"

Comment: check the actual query by placing a echo $sql; at the end of that script.

Comment: well you need learn prepared statement because this way is already obsolete and vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: This is an example of a query that works: $sql = "UPDATE workout SET ProgressiveOverload = ".$progressive." WHERE WorkoutID = ".$currentWorkoutID."";

Comment: @Andy I think the last two  duoble quotes can be removed.

Comment: A clue in your question.. ` 0000-00-00 ` Supply your date column a properly formatted date `("Y-m-d")`

Comment: what return `$date = date("y/m/d");`?

Comment: This is the echo'd sql statement UPDATE workout SET Date = 16/11/25 WHERE WorkoutID = 45

Comment: include the single quotes for date `'` should be `Date = '16/11/25'`

Comment: This statement works when I type it directly into myAdmin: UPDATE workout SET Date = '16/11/04' WHERE WorkoutID = 45

Comment: Aye it works now, I needed single quotes around the ".$date.". Thanks Juan.

Comment: sorry your teacher isn't very good at it. Please read up on prepared statements. That's the proper way to use SQL. String concatenation is inferior. The answer you have accepted works in this instance, but there will be plenty of others where it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include single quotes `'` for date

```
$sql = "UPDATE workout SET Date = '".$date."'  WHERE WorkoutID = ".$currentWorkoutID."";
                                  ^         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE workout SET `Date` = '".$date."' WHERE WorkoutID = ".$currentWorkoutID."";
```

**Because date is a reserved keyword**

Answer (score 0):

i agrre with the answer
$sql = "UPDATE workout SET Date = '".$date."'  WHERE WorkoutID = ".$currentWorkoutID."";

because maybe the type of Date is String ,
hope to help you,thank you